# Utilizing goroutines and channels for top-to-bottom tree building function

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I'm new with golang and channels/goroutines, but I understand the concept and simple usage.

Now I'm trying to implement concurrent tree building function, the algorithm is pretty simple - from top to bottom *for each node I add 2 children and then for each child I do the same operation **depthLimit** times*. Here is the code for non-concurent one:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Node struct {
    Name     string
    Children []Node
}

func main() {
    mainNode := Node{"p", nil}
    AddChildrenToNode(&mainNode, 4, 0)

    b, _ := json.MarshalIndent(mainNode, "", "  ")
    fmt.Println(string(b)) // print as json
}

func AddChildrenToNode(node *Node, depthLimit int, curDepth int) {
    curDepth++
    if curDepth >= depthLimit {
        return // reached depth limit
    }

    time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond) // imitating hard work c:
    fmt.Print(".")                     // status indicator
    // add children
    node.Children = []Node{
        Node{node.Name + "-l", nil},
        Node{node.Name + "-r", nil},
    }
    for idx, _ := range node.Children {
        AddChildrenToNode(&node.Children[idx], depthLimit, curDepth) // run this for every created child, recursively
    }
}
```

But now I face difficulties rewriting it for goroutine usage. The problem is we can't actually know when 'building' is finished and signal to block/unblock main. Am I missing something? I also tried to play with *sync.WaitingGroup*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can introduce goroutines into this algorithm is to use a separate goroutine for the addition of child nodes, assuming you can't really add those before you finish the "hard work" section.

```
func AddChildrenToNode(node *Node, wg *sync.WaitGroup,depthLimit int, curDepth int) {
  // work
  go func() {
    defer wg.Done()
    node.Children = []Node{
        Node{node.Name + "-l", nil},
        Node{node.Name + "-r", nil},
    }
    for idx, _ := range node.Children {
        AddChildrenToNode(&node.Children[idx], depthLimit, curDepth) // run this for every created child, recursively
    }
  }()
}
```

With this scheme, you end up creating 2^(depth-1)-1 goroutines, so you can wait in main for them to complete:

```
func main() {
 ...
  wg:=sync.WaitGroup{}
  wg.Add((1<<(depth-1))-1)
  AddChildrenToNode(&mainNode, 4, 0)
  wg.Wait()
  ...
```

There are other ways this can be done, like adding a goroutine for left-right nodes.

Comment: Sadly it will only work for binary trees, but when the tree is dynamic (for example we could end up with shorter length paths or the number of children is dynamic (like generating the tree for dir structure)). Thanks for the answer, I guess it's just impossible to make use of goroutines in this case :(

Comment: Actually I was wrong, I posted the final answer below

Answer (score 0):

I guess i finally figured out how to implement it. @burak-serdar's answer helped a lot. Actually instead of pushing the whole *AddChildrenToNode* to the goroutine pool, we can add to our wait group and then use a lambda to only run the next layer in a goroutine. And because we are adding to our wait group before this layer - it's guaranteed to not overflow the 'dones' value so we will always exit when all the children are populated. Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type Node struct {
    Name     string
    Children []Node
}

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())

    mainNode := Node{"p", nil}
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    AddChildrenToNode(&mainNode, 4, 0, &wg)
    wg.Wait()

    b, _ := json.MarshalIndent(mainNode, "", "  ")
    fmt.Println(string(b)) // print as json
}

func AddChildrenToNode(node *Node, depthLimit int, curDepth int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    curDepth++
    if curDepth >= depthLimit {
        return // reached depth limit
    }

    // Dynamic children count
    cN := rand.Intn(5)
    for i := 0; i <= cN; i++ {
        node.Children = append(node.Children, Node{node.Name + "-l", nil})
    }

    //node.Children = []Node{}

    time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond) // imitating hard work c:

    for idx, _ := range node.Children {
        fmt.Println(".")
        wg.Add(1) // it will always lag behind the next done so the flow wont be broken
        go func(idx int) {
            AddChildrenToNode(&node.Children[idx], depthLimit, curDepth, wg) // run this for every created child, recursively
            wg.Done()
        }(idx)
    }
}
```